# How to repeat single hash multiple times in one array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, faker

I want to create dozens of logins that rely on data from this array, logins:

```
    logins = [
        {
            email: Faker::Internet.email,
            password: "password",
            first_name: Faker::Name.first_name,
            last_name: Faker::Name.last_name 
        },
        {
            email: Faker::Internet.email,
            password: "password",
            first_name: Faker::Name.first_name,
            last_name: Faker::Name.last_name 
        }
    ]
```

What is a better way of writing this array rather than copy and pasting that hash dozens of times? I am familiar with x.times do but that wouldn't work on an array.

Here's the code where I pass in the logins:

```
    logins.each do |login|
         li = LoginInformation.new(login: login[:email], password: login[:password])
         if UserManager.save(li)
                company_ids.each do |id|
                  li.contacts.create(first_name: login[:first_name], last_name: login[:last_name], email_address: login[:email], company_id: id, is_employee: true)
                end
         end
    end
```

Comment: You might want to use `accepts_nested_attributes` instead to create both records at once.

Comment: Use [factory_girl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl) gem for it. Then  you'll be able to write something like `FactoryGirl.create_list(:login, 25)`, which is much cleaner than all current answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to simplify the creation of your `logins` array is to pass the hash object with the included `Faker` methods as a block, like so:

```
logins = Array.new(10) { { email: Faker::Internet.email, password: 'password', first_name: Faker::Name.first_name, last_name: Faker::Name.last_name } }
```

You can replace the `10` in this example with the number of elements required for your use case.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

`.times` returns an enumerator that you can call `.map` on to get an array.

```
logins = 10.times.map do
  {
     email: Faker::Internet.email,
     password: "password",
     first_name: Faker::Name.first_name,
     last_name: Faker::Name.last_name 
  }
end
```

Or use `Array.new` as mentioned by Zoran Pesic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use for loop to insert the values multiple times

```
logins=[]
    for i in 0..10
    logins <<
            {
               email: Faker::Internet.email,
               password: "password",
               first_name: Faker::Name.first_name,
               last_name: Faker::Name.last_name 
            }
    end
```

Comment: You can use `10.times{ login << ..}` as well

Answer (score 0):

Can do this way also:

```
10.times do
  login = { email: Faker::Internet.email, password: 'password', first_name: Faker::Name.first_name, last_name: Faker::Name.last_name }
  li = LoginInformation.new(login: login[:email], password: login[:password])
  if UserManager.save(li)
    company_ids.each do |id|
      li.contacts.create(first_name: login[:first_name], last_name: login[:last_name], email_address: login[:email], company_id: id, is_employee: true)
    end
  end
end
```